# My MVC3 app is adding "/Controllers/" folder to all my links

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controllers

I've inherited an MVC3 .NET web app, which had all the controllers for the site in a separate project to the main web app. Not sure why this was the case. As it's a small app, I decided (for "neatness") to move the controller code back into the main web project, under the usual "Controllers" folder.

"Controllers" project folders:

- Admin
- Members
- Config

Moved above code into main Web project under "Controllers" folder, ie:

- Controllers

  - Admin
  - Members
  - Config

The problem now is, all the links generated by the code include "/Controllers/" in the path, assumedly because the controller code is now in a "Controllers" project folder. Is this a simple MVC issue to fix? Or would it likely be a flaw in code itself, in that it relies on where the code files run from to generate links?

Comment: how are the links getting generated? What is your default route? Any other custom routes that would be messing this up?

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT; thanks, it's using SharpArch's ActionLinkForAreas to generate the links. Signature: ActionLinkForAreas<TController>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<TController>> action, string linkText). I'm new to SharpArch - how would I debug this to see why it's adding the "controllers" path to links?